# Trying to simulate Http request using C# cannot debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to use C# to simulate HTTP requests, but Visual Studio reported an error when I debugged the code.

> The debugger cannot continue running the process and cannot start
> debugging

```
public static string GetData(string url,string data)
{
 string strResult = "";
 try
 {
     url = url+ "?" + data;

     HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
     HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result; //debug

     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
         strResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
     }
 }
 catch(Exception)
 {

     throw;
 }
```

It's worth mentioning that I also have a class library in this solution, but I still have no clue.

Comment: Not related but you [are using httpclient wrong ...](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: This link helped me using httpclient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for this issue is that the target project debugged by Visual Studio itself does not support debugging. Because you have a class library project in the same solution, if you set up multiple startup projects, then the debugger trying to debug the class library will cause it to fail to run normally.

Please follow these steps:

Right-click the solution=>Properties=>Common Properties=>Startup Project=>Single startup project

Set it as a non-ClassLibrary project

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I can now start the debugger